# converting text file to json in python

Tags: python, json

I have multiple documents that together are approximately 400 GB and I want to convert them to json format in order to drop to elasticsearch for analysis.

Each file is approximately 200 MB.

Original file looked like:

```
IUGJHHGF@BERLIN:lhfrjy
0t7yfudf@WARSAW:qweokm246
0t7yfudf@CRACOW:Er747474
0t7yfudf@cracow:kui666666
000t7yf@Vienna:1йй2ц2й2цй2цц3у
```

It has the characters that are not only English. key1 is always separated with @, where city was separated either by ; or :

After I have parsed it with code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# coding: utf8
import json


with open('2') as f:
   for line in f:
      s1 = line.find("@")
      rest = line[s1+1:]
      if rest.find(";") != -1:
         if rest.find(":") != -1:
            print "FOUND BOTH : ; "
            s2 = -0
         else:
            s2 = s1+1+rest.find(";")
      elif rest.find(":") != -1:
         s2 = s1+1+rest.find(":")
      else:
         print "FOUND NO : ; "
         s2 = -0

      key1 = line[:s1]
      city = line[s1+1:s2]
      description = line[s2+1:len(line)-1]
```

All file looks like:

```
RRS12345 Cracow Sunflowers
RRD12345 Berin Data
```

After that parsing I want to have the output:

```
  {  
   "location_data":[  
      {  
         "key1":"RRS12345",
         "city":"Cracow",
         "description":"Sunflowers"
      },
      {  
         "key1":"RRD123dsd45",
         "city":"Berlin",
         "description":"Data"
      },
      {  
         "key1":"RRD123dsds45",
         "city":"Berlin",
         "description":"1йй2ц2й2цй2цц3у"
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I convert it to the required json format quickly, where we do not have only English characters?

Comment: Can you show what you tried and describe how exactly it failed?

Comment: Do you need to use Python in particular, or would a faster non-Python solution do?

Comment: Do any of the cities have spaces in their names? Or spaces in the descriptions? If so, what does that look like?

Comment: No spaces in the names exist. The language does not matter.

Comment: I could do theoretically print at the end of the script that I have wrote and force that json syntax manually, but that is just so dump solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import json


def process_text_to_json():
    location_data = []
    with open("file.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.split()
            location_data.append({"key1": line[0], "city": line[1], "description": line[2]})

    location_data = {"location_data": location_data}
    return json.dumps(location_data)
```

Output sample:

> {"location_data": [{"city": "Cracow", "key1": "RRS12345", "description": "Sunflowers"}, {"city": "Berin", "key1": "RRD12345", "description": "Data"}, {"city": "Cracow2", "key1": "RRS12346", "description": "Sunflowers"}, {"city": "Berin2", "key1": "RRD12346", "description": "Data"}, {"city": "Cracow3", "key1": "RRS12346", "description": "Sunflowers"}, {"city": "Berin3", "key1": "RRD12346", "description": "Data"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each line and form your dict.

**Ex:**

```
d = {"location_data":[]}
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        val = line.split()
        d["location_data"].append({"key1": val[0], "city": val[1], "description": val[2]})

print(d)
```